# How to split a list in half by chunks of n?

Tags: python, list

I have list, let's say:

```
main = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

I want to split it into two list, with a step of `n`. i.e. first `n` elements will go to `list1`, next `n` elements will go to `list2` and so on.

So the result from the above list with `n=2` will be:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 5, 6]
list2 = [3, 4, 7, 8]
```

Because first two elements `1, 2` go to `list1`,  next two elements `3, 4` go to `list2` and so on.

Comment: Hi. We expect you to at least post some code you tried, then explain the errors or obstacles you're facing.

Comment: There are many ways to do this, but you could loop on indexes, starting at 0 with a step of 4, then deal with the 4 elements from each index.

Comment: Don't use `list` as a variable name.  Doing so masks the builtin.

Comment: what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 1):

If you convert your list to a numpy array, this is an easy way:

```
main_list= np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
list1range=np.array(np.arange(len(main_list))//2)
list1indices=np.where(list1range%2==0)
list1=main_list[list1indices]
list2=np.delete(main_list,list1indices)
```

---

```
[1 2 5 6] [3 4 7 8]
```

And as append is very slow, I would rather suggest this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 working methods, amongst others

```
main_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

One method - use indexes 0, 4, ... then deal with each quartet of elements from each index; of course, it requires main_list's length to be a multiple of 4:

```
list1, list2 = [], []
for i in range(0,len(main_list), 4):
    list1 += main_list[i:i+2]
    list2 += main_list[i+2:i+4]
```

Another method - first group pairs of elements from main_list, then fill list1 and list2 respectively from the pairs at even and odd positions:

```
pairs = list(zip(*[iter(main_list)]*2))
list1 = [element for even_pair in pairs[::2] for element in even_pair]
list2 = [element for odd_pair in pairs[1::2] for element in odd_pair]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
main = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

list1 = []
list2 = []
for i, x in enumerate(main):
    (list1, list2)[i//2%2].append(x)

print(list1)
print(list2)
```

I just go through the values in order and append each to the correct list.

Dividing the index by 2 gives me streaks of 2 elements: `i//2` becomes 0,0,1,1,2,2,3,3.

The `%2` rotates through 0 and 1: `i//2%2` becomes 0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1. Which selects the proper list from the tuple `(list1, list2)`.

Comment: @MichaelM. It's not my question.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say can you add an explanation to your answer?